# Vue data property not reactive

Tags: vue.js, reactive

Considering the code below, I can not make the `active` data property reactive. In this case I would like to show a div only on mouseover on an image.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <img @mouseover="showInfo" class="cursor-pointer w-full" :src="project.images[0].url" width="100%">
        <div v-show="active" class="bg-red h-12">
            Info about the image
        </div>
    </div>    
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['project'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                active: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            showInfo: () => {
                this.active = !this.active;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have tried using v-if instead and printing `active` but to no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simpler if you just change the value in `HTML` and you don't require a separate method for that.

```
@mouseover="active = !active"
```

It will look like this,

```
<div>
   <img @mouseover="active = !active" class="cursor-pointer w-full" :src="project.images[0].url" width="100%">
   <div v-show="active" class="bg-red h-12">
     Info about the image
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Don't use arrow functions to define methods, `this` will not work.

Just replace

```
        showInfo: () => {
            this.active = !this.active;
        }
```

With:

```
        showInfo() {
            this.active = !this.active;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data() {
    return {
         active: false
     }
},
```

Update your data like the one above.

Also I'd rename your function to `toggleInfo` as it can also hide it on mouse out.

And remove the arrow.

```
toggleInfo() {
     this.active = !this.active;
 }
```

Comment: `data() {}` is just the shorthand version of `data: function() {}`

Comment: Yes. Now if you were using a style guide compare the main function of data to the methods.

Comment: Yes, that was more for consistency